# boost fusion and boost qi - compile-time error

Tags: c++, boost

I am unable to compile the following code:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <string>

struct function
{
  std::string ret_type;
  std::string name;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  function,
  (std::string, ret_type)
  (std::string, name)
)

int main() {}
```

MSVC-11.0 with boost 1.54 gives me the following errors:

```
1>main.cpp(6084): error C3203: 'function' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Sequence', expected a real type
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2955: 'boost::function' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          e:\libs\boost_1_54_0\boost\function\function_fwd.hpp(33) : see declaration of 'boost::function'
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::fusion::traits::tag_of' is not a specialization of a class template
1>main.cpp(6084): error C3203: 'function' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Seq', expected a real type
1>          e:\libs\boost_1_54_0\boost\function\function_fwd.hpp(33) : see declaration of 'boost::function'
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::fusion::extension::access::struct_member' is not a specialization of a class template
1>          e:\libs\boost_1_54_0\boost\function\function_fwd.hpp(33) : see declaration of 'boost::function'
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::fusion::extension::struct_member_name' is not a specialization of a class template
1>          e:\libs\boost_1_54_0\boost\function\function_fwd.hpp(33) : see declaration of 'boost::function'
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::fusion::extension::struct_size' is not a specialization of a class template
1>          e:\libs\boost_1_54_0\boost\function\function_fwd.hpp(33) : see declaration of 'boost::function'
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::fusion::extension::struct_is_view' is not a specialization of a class template
1>          e:\libs\boost_1_54_0\boost\function\function_fwd.hpp(33) : see declaration of 'boost::function'
1>main.cpp(6084): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::mpl::sequence_tag' is not a specialization of a class template
```

Everything is fine if I remove the "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp" including or explicitly tells that function structure is placed inside global namespace:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  ::function,
  (std::string, ret_type)
  (std::string, name)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` macro, it creates some types and places them inside the `boost` namespace. The definition of those types will reference the struct name that you gave it.

In your case, you gave the struct a name which is the same as a name already existing in the boost namespace: `boost::function`, which is apparently indirectly included by the boost qi header. Since the generated code is in the `boost` namespace, it thinks you meant to refer to `boost::function` rather than to your type `::function`.

For this reason, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) says: "struct_name should be the fully namespace qualified name of the struct to be adapted". So your solution of adding the global namespace qualifier `::` before the type name is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is somehting inside the macro scope of boost fusion that is called `function`, and it seems that it has priority over your type. It works if you change the name of your struct :

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <string>

struct my_function
{
  std::string ret_type;
  std::string name;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  my_function,
  (std::string, ret_type)
  (std::string, name)
)

int main() {}
```